# Execute AngularJS function after bootstrap validation is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and AngularJS, so I don't know how to solve the following issue.

I am having an HTML file with bootstrap and validation.js with Angular and PHP file.

While user clicks the submit button, I need to validate the fields using Bootstrap validation. If validation is true then I need to call the JS file.

The issue here is, AgularJS onclick function started to work when user presses the submit button. It won't wait for bootstrap validation to finish.

Please give some idea to how to do this.

Comment: Please give more explanation. A sample code on what you are doing and description on where you are facing problem will help others to answer your question.

Comment: There is no such validation available in the Bootstrap. Bootstrap is a CSS library. Are you using any other validation like jQuery validation or so? What kind of validation you are doing?

Comment: Am used bootsrap validation js file eg: http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/

Comment: pls refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent submit event with `ng-disabled` attribute on submit button like below.

```
<form ng-click="yourAngularMethod()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="yourModel0" required>
   <input type="text" ng-model="yourModel1" required>
   <input type="text" ng-model="yourModel2" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Fire!" ng-disabled="yourCondition">
</form>
```

Also you can show your error like below:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="errorState">
{{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

Comment: if it's div then what we should do ?

Comment: great thanks furkan,still i have some confusion i try to figure out using ur idea,if i can't i will ask u help .thanks agin.